# Two UIScrollViews, one scrolls vertically and the other horizontally

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I found that `Yahoo weather app` has 2 scroll views, one can scroll vertically and the other can scroll horizontally.

These 2 scroll views are overlapped. How can I know which scroll view to scroll, based on the gesture?

For example, if I swipe up, the first scroll view should scroll up and the second one should remain unchanged.

Comment: Have you set limits on the direction each can scroll. They should work it out for themselves...

Comment: One would imagine that the vertical scrolling is courtesy of a UIScrollView embedded as part of the content of a horizontal scrolling UIScrollView. Assuming you limit the content sizes so that each UIScrollView will only scroll in one dimension I'm sure the UIScrollView implementations will sort it all out for you...

Comment: Tableview + ScrolviewInside Cell, [Check this app](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/nordic/id662056826?mt=8)

Comment: I limit the content size of both scroll view, but only the upper scroll view can be scrolled.